# Deploy .net core 3.0 on AZURE or Local

Tags: c#, azure, api, iis, asp.net-core

Over the last 2 days i twisted my head around deploying my WEB API.

App specification: WEB API .NET CORE 3.0 Preview 4

Firstly i tried to deploy on Azure using App Services.
Seems like they don't support .net core 3.0 but i don't really understand this since you can wrap everything in your package, wasn't this done in order to be deploy-able everywhere ? 
When i'm trying to access the websitei get a 
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure which i didn't managed to fix.

--I tried to do the same with a clean project, still same issue--

Secondly i created a virtual machine (VM) and deploy on VM.

Here i get a internal server error and i cannot debug (any tips are welcome)

Third I deployed on local IIS, here i get the following error:
"Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"

I added the permissions to IIS_IUSRS but after this i get a infinite loop

--The same i get with the clean project--

Am i doing something wrong , what could i do to deploy my Web Api Project.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a hard dependency on ASP.NET Core module, which you won't be able to fix on Azure App Service, and that's why you got the error message. You can easily reproduce the same error if you manually create a mismatch on your machine. More information can be found in https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation suggests that it is possible to deploy preview versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service), although I haven't tried it. [This blogger](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2019/04/22/Publishing-ASPNET-Core-3-Web-API-to-Azure-App-Service-with-Http2.aspx) encountered the same problem you did, and resolved it using these instructions. He says:

> This document covers two different ways to fix this issue – you can
>   either install the preview site extensions for ASP.NET Core 3, or you
>   can simply change your deployment to be a self-contained application.
>   In this case we’re going to go with deploying a self-contained
>   application, since this reduces any external dependencies which seems
>   sensible to me.

So it seems you are correct that building a self-contained package is one way of solving this, but you have to specifically ask for that when you publish.

Comment: After another day of trials, i gave up to 3.0 preview and went back to 2.2 . Now everything works as expected. Still just out of curiosity i will try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I got it with deploying the app self-contained like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0#deploy-the-app-self-contained

Comment: Self-contained didn't work with X64 but was okay when I changed it back to the default X86 with the current .NET Core 3.0.100-preview5-011568 version for an ASP.NET Blazor server-side site.

Comment: Hi @TonyWall, how can i changes X64 to X86. Do you share any steps

Comment: I was able to deploy successfully on 3.0 preview 8 by installing the extension for core 3.0 x86 (free tier) then going to app Settings > Configuration > General Settings where I set the Stack to .NET 4.7. After doing that my Blazor app lit up.

Comment: NET Core 3.0 deployment on App Service Windows has been completed on October 11th 2019

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/118